# Terraform Inconsistent Azure VM Names

Tags: azure, terraform

I have the following terraform code that creates multiple instances of a Azure VM based on a variable called nb_instance

```
module "create-servers" { 
  
   source              = "../../Modules/Create-Vms" 
   resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
   vm_hostname         = "testvm"
   nb_instances = 2
```

On my create-servers module, I have the following code

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm-windows" { 
   count                         = var.nb_instances 
   name                          = "${var.vm_hostname}${format("%02d",count.index+1)}" 
   resource_group_name           = data.azurerm_resource_group.vm.name
```

Which works great, however I'm getting inconsitent naming convention between the Azure resource and the actual server name of the VM.

Azure displays the server as testvm01 and testvm02 however the server's actual OS name is testvm-1 and testvm-2 . My desired name is testvm02 which is what I expected within the module. Is there a workaround for this to keep both names consistent?

Comment: try setting os_profile.computer_name property, too. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#os_profile

Comment: awesome! that was it indeed!

Comment: glad to hear it! I posted as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You also need to set the property `os_profile.computer_name`

https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#os_profile